# prestashop: Display method results in JSON

Tags: json, module, hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm going to develop a method inside my Prestashop module to fetch list of products and return the result as JSON. 
I have no problem to get list of products however I don't know to use which hooks and how to return JSON result instead of returning back to a Prestashop page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use a specific controller in your module. the result of the controller is available by an URL.
(Your controller class have to extend the "ModuleFrontController" class)

In your module controller, you should change the default constructor by:

```
public function __construct($response = array()) {
    parent::__construct($response);
    $this->display_header = false;
    $this->display_header_javascript = false;
    $this->display_footer = false;
}
```

And, in your "postProcess" method, simply echo the string you want, using this for example:

```
$json = json_encode( (array)$object );
```

Finally, in a template, you can generate a link to this controller using:

```
{$link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'mycontrolleurname', [], true)}
```

Comment: So how can I can directly call module to show this output? I mean which url will call this module?

Comment: In your module files, in the directory "mymodulename\controllers\front", you can create a php file named "mycontrollername.php", this way : class MymodulenameMycontrollernameModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{ ... } with the __construct() and the postProcess() methods. In the postProcess you can get the POST or GET parameter, and "echo" the response you want. the URL to call this controlles is : [link](http://www.yourdomaine.com/module/mymodulename/mycontrollername?anyvar=anyvalue)